# Convex hexagon's diagonals.

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to have a convex hexagon whose longest diagonal is less than twice of its shortest side? Justify.

A convex hexagon is a hexagon where the line connecting any 2 vertices never go outside of the hexagon.

Comment: Sorry for the unnecessary bumping, but is there someone who has an idea for this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consicer an equilateral triangle $ABC$ and make it a hexagon by adding vertices $D,E,F$ in the middle of the edges.
This (degenerate) hexagon has all side lengths $AF=FB=BD=DC=CE=EA=a=\frac12$ and diagonals $AB, BC, CA$ of lengths $b=1$ and diagonals $AD, BE, CF$ of lengths $c=\frac{\sqrt3} 2<1$.
If we slightly move the vertices $D,E,F$ away from the centre, the side lengths $a$ and diagonals $c$ grow larger and diagonals $b$ remain unchanged. By continuity, a sufficiently small such movement produces a hexagon as requested.

---

For an explicit construction: Start with an equilateral triangle $ABC$ with center $O$, let $D$ be the intersection of $AO$ with the circle around $A$ through $B$ and $C$ (such that $O$ is between $A$ and $D$). Similarly construct $E$ with $BO$ and the circle around $B$ through $A$ and $C$ and $F$ with $CO$ and the circle around $C$ through $A$ and $B$.
Then all diagonals of $AFBDCE$ have length $|AB|$ and all sides have length $|AF|>\frac12 |AB|$.

[image: A convex hexagon with all diagonals 1.93 times as long as the sides]